# Perl Regular Expression extracting sub-string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a String variable containing something like `ABCD.asd.qwe.com:/dir1`.
I want to extract the `ABCD` portion i.e. the portion from beginning till the first appearance of `.`. The problem is that there can be almost any characters (only alphanumeric) of any length before the `.`. So I created this regexp.

```
if($arg =~ /(.*?\.?)/)
{
    my $temp_name = $1;
}
```

However it is giving me blank string. The logic is that :

```
.*? - any character non-greedily
\.? - till first or none appearance of .
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you tryint to extract `ABCD` or `ABCD.`? Will the `.` always be there in the input?

Comment: I want to extract only ABCD & not including the dot.

Comment: What about my second question. Will there always be a `.` in the input?

Comment: if you are asking whether the input will be .ABCD.asd.... then the answer is no.

Comment: No, is "ABCD" possible?

Comment: If you are asking whether only ABCD will be the input then again the answer is no. The format in question is the only valid one for my requirement, everything else is the user's fault. So if you are trying to suggest that there might be strange behaviour for certain types of inputs then that will not happen because the input is strictly in the format as mentioned. PS: If you did not notice, the input is actually the full network path of a Sun Solaris machine, that's why it will always be in the given format. Hope that clears some doubts ;)

Comment: Then all that's needed is `/^([^.]*)/`. No need to for any lookaheads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead use negative character class like this

```
^[^.]+
```

---

`[^.]` would match any character except `.`

`[^.]+` would match 1 to many characters(except `.`)

`^` depicts the start of string

**OR**

```
^.+?(?=\.|$)
```

---

`(?=)` is a lookahead which checks for a particular pattern after the current position..So for text `abcdad` with regex `a(?=b)` only `a` would match

`$` depicts the end of line(if used with multiline option) or end of string(if used with singleline option)

Comment: Hey @Anirudh, both the solutions are working!
Thanks man!
But can you please explain the logic behind that?

Comment: @Cool_Coder The logic is very simple. The first `^` means "`the string must start here`". The next `[^.]+` means "`any character that isn't a period, repeated 1 or more times.`" Hence it selects up until the first period.

Comment: @Anirudh so ^[^x]+ would match any character from start till the first appearance of x, right?

Comment: @Cool_Coder it would match till the last appearance of character which is not `.`..so it would match everything if there's no `.`

Comment: I meant if instead I used ^[^C]+ then this would catch AB right?

Comment: `$` doesn't mean end-of-string, `\z` does. `$` means `(?=\n?\z)`

Comment: That's even worse. It's not affected whatsoever by /s, and again, it doesn't mean end-of-string. Ever.

Answer (score 3):

`\.?` doesn't mean "till first or none appearance of `.`". It means "a `.` here or not".

---

If the first character of the string is `.`:

- `.*?` matches 0 chars at position 0.
- `\.?` matches 1 char at position 0.

`$1` contains `.`.

---

If the first character of the string isn't `.`:

- `.*?` matches 0 chars at position 0.
- `\.?` matches 0 chars at position 0.

`$1` is empty.

---

To match `ABCD`, the following would do:

```
/^(.*?)\./
```

However, I hate the non-greedy modifier. It's fragile, in the sense that it stops doing what you want if you use two in the same pattern. I'd use the following instead ("match non-periods"):

```
/^([^.]*)\./
```

or even just

```
/^([^.]*)/
```

Comment: (The `^` isn't necessary, but it's a good habit as it can be prevent a crazy amount of backtracking on failure.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the incorrectness of my initial approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;

my $string = "ABCD.asd.qwe.com:/dir1";

$string =~ /([^.]+)/;
my $capture = $1;
print"$capture\n";
```

OR you can also use **[Split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)** function like,

```
my $sub_string = ( split /\./, $string )[0];
print"$sub_string\n";
```

Note in general: For the explaination of Regex (understanding the complex Regex), take a look at [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm) module.

Comment: `my ($capture) = $string =~ /^([^.]+)/;` would be more robust. (Bonus: doesn't use global vars.)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if($arg =~ /(.*?)\..+/)
{
    my $temp_name = $1; 
}
```

That would match anything before the first `.` .
You could change the `.+` to .* if your input may end after the first `.`.
You could change the first `.*?` to `.+?` if you are sure that there is always at least one character before the first `.`.

Comment: The added `.+` is useless. Firstly, it's the same as just `.`. Secondly, all it does is make sure the `.` is followed by a non-newline, and the OP did not express any interest in verifying that. So why did you add it?